# Linear system of ODEs - about the comparison of different solution methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

**System**
\begin{equation*}
    \dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)=A\,\mathbf{x}(t)
\end{equation*}
with $\mathbf{x}(t)\in C^1:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n,\,A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},\,t\in\mathbb{R}$

---

**Method I**
\begin{align*}
    e^{-At}\,\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)
    &=e^{-At}\,A\,\mathbf{x}(t)\\
    \frac{d}{dt}\Big[e^{-At}\,\mathbf{x}(t)\Big]
    &=0\\
    \int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{d}{d\tau}\Big[e^{-A\tau}\,\mathbf{x}(\tau)\Big]\,d\tau
    &=0\\
    e^{-At}\,\mathbf{x}(t)-e^{-At_0}\,\mathbf{x}(t_0)
    &=0
\end{align*}
Eventually
$$\boxed{\mathbf{x}(t)=e^{A(t-t_0)}\,\mathbf{x}(t_0)}$$
Note: 'Method I' automatically assure existence and uniqueness of solutions

---

**Method II**

"Try" a solution of the form $$\mathbf{x}_\omega(t)=\mathbf{x}_0(\omega)\,e^{\omega t}$$
Plugging into the system, we get
\begin{align*}
\omega\,\mathbf{x}_0(\omega)\,e^{\omega t}
&=A\,\mathbf{x}_0(\omega)\,e^{\omega t}
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{equation}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\; (A-I\,\omega)\,\mathbf{x}_0(\omega)=0\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;(1)
\end{equation}
Condition for (1) to not have trivial solution $\mathbf{x}_0(\omega)=\mathbf{0}$ as unique solution is that
\begin{equation}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\, det(A-I\,\omega)=0\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;(2)
\end{equation}
Such condition is called charateristic equation and can also be expressed in the form
\begin{equation}
\qquad\qquad a_0+a_1\,\omega+a_2\,\omega^2+..+a_n\,\omega^n=0\qquad\qquad(3)
\end{equation}
Solving eq. (2) (or alternatively eq. (3)) for $\omega$, then solving eq. (1) for each value of $\omega_i$ so obtained, one ends up with a set of solutions $\mathbf{x}_0(\omega_i)$.

Eventually, since the system is linear, it can be easly proved that a linear combination of the solutions found is also solution, so we can write our solutions in the general form
$$\boxed{\mathbf{x}(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\,\mathbf{x}_0\,(\omega_i)\,e^{\omega_i t}}$$
where $c_i$ are unknown coefficients to be found imposing, for example, an initial condition on $\mathbf{x}(t_0)$

---

**Question(s)**

Hoping that all my passages are correct, i have a few questions about the comparision of the two methods

1. While 'Method I' assure existence and uniqueness of solution, 'Method II' does not. In some engineering problems 'Method II' is actually the most used, so i was asking myself why we work with that, there's a way to show that all the solutions found for 'Method II' are actually the complete set of them?
2. The solution "tried" in 'Method II' resemble to me the form we end up with 'Method I'. There's a way to pass from one to the other? Or maybe a way to express solution of 'Method I' in the form of the solution of 'Method II'?

---

Regarding 2., following procedure brought by @Ian
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}_{II}(t)&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i(t_0)\,\mathbf{x}_0\,(\omega_i)\,e^{\omega_i t}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c(\omega_i,t_0)\,\mathbf{x}_0\,(\omega_i)\,e^{\omega_i t}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{x}_0\,(\omega_i)\,e^{\omega_i t}\,c(\omega_i,t_0)\\
&=\mathbf{X}_0(\boldsymbol\omega)\,e^{diag(\boldsymbol\omega)t}\,\mathbf{c}(\boldsymbol\omega,t_0)\\
\,\\
\mathbf{x}_I(t)&=e^{A(t-t_0)}\,\mathbf{x}(t_0)\\
&=P\,e^{J(\boldsymbol\omega)\,(t-t_0)}\,P^{-1}\,\mathbf{x}(t_0)\\
&=\underset{\mathbf{X}_0(\boldsymbol\omega)}{\underbrace{P}}\,e^{J(\boldsymbol\omega)\,t}\,\underset{\mathbf{c}(\boldsymbol\omega,t_0)}{\underbrace{e^{-J(\boldsymbol\omega)\,t_0}\,P^{-1}\,\mathbf{x}(t_0)}}
\end{align}

having defined $\boldsymbol\omega\equiv\{\omega_1..\omega_n\}$, $\mathbf{X}_0(\boldsymbol\omega)\equiv \{\mathbf{x}_0(\omega_1)..\mathbf{x}_0(\omega_n)\}$, $\mathbf{c}(\boldsymbol\omega,t_0)\equiv\{c(\omega_1,t_0) ... c(\omega_n,t_0)\}$ and $diag(\boldsymbol\omega)$ as the diagonal matrix having diagonal entries vector $\boldsymbol\omega$

**Conclusion**: To have $\mathbf{x}_{I}(t)=\mathbf{x}_{II}(t)$, $A$ needs to be diagonalizable, which can make $J(\boldsymbol\omega)=diag(\boldsymbol\omega)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One way is to just invoke Picard-Lindelof to say solutions to IVPs with this class of equations exist and are unique automatically. Then the matter of noticing that all solutions are of the (generalized) form in method 2 is just a matter of showing that you can pick a solution of the desired form for any particular initial condition. This requires the linear independence of the eigenvectors (and if applicable generalized eigenvectors) which is a general part of the theory of linear algebra.
2. Yes, they're really the same. The procedure is to say $A=P J P^{-1}$ where $J$ is the Jordan normal form. As a result, $e^{A(t-t_0)}=P e^{J(t-t_0)} P^{-1}$. Breaking down the structure:

- The multiplication by $P$ on the left generates the appearance of the eigenvectors in the expansion in method 2.
- The multiplication by $e^{J(t-t_0)}$ gives the exponentials in each term. Note that you can instead write $P e^{Jt} e^{-Jt_0} P^{-1}=P e^{Jt} Q$ where $Q=e^{-Jt_0} P^{-1}$. This amounts to "hiding $t_0$ inside of the $c_i$" in the notation of your second method.
- The multiplication by $P^{-1}$ gives you the $c_i$, which is to say the coefficients of the initial condition in an expansion into eigenvectors, from the initial condition.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. If i'm understanding correctly, existence and uniqueness is proved through Picard-Lindelof applied to Method I, and, using 'Jordan matrix procedure', this result can be extended also to the solution of Method II. Regarding this, it would be very appreciated if you could make the passages explicit as i'm having trouble deriving one from the other (due to the presence of $(t-t_0)$ and not great familiarity with Jordan form). Thank you

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta The first method gives you existence/uniqueness for free; essentially all you need is that $e^{-At}$ always exists and is never singular, and to know what its derivative is. So Picard-Lindelof is not really required. Where you actually need Picard-Lindelof is for the second approach. Also, for most purposes you can think of the Jordan form as the diagonal form, I only mentioned it since you're looking at the general case in your question.

Comment: Ok perfect, my actual issue was in fact hidden in the Jordan form which i read is not always diagonal, but then we would need some additional conditions on $A$..? What you mean by 'most purposes'?

Comment: Actually, thinking back i think term $e^{-Jt_0}$ should better go on the left side as function of $\omega$, i'll write my passages in a minute, to better explain that

Comment: Ok, added in question

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta "Most" square matrices, in a number of different senses of "most", are diagonalizable. In this case the Jordan form is indeed diagonal. When it isn't, you have terms corresponding to generalized eigenvectors, which can still be handled; you end up with terms behaving like $t^k e^{ct}$ in the expansion, where $k$ is a positive integer. You can see this in action by actually doing the power series for the exponential, for example try simplifying the power series of $\exp \left ( \begin{bmatrix} t & t \\ 0 & t \end{bmatrix} \right )$ by hand. It is not super difficult.

Comment: Mm i see, but then we cannot conclude 'Method 2' represents all solutions, but just a fraction of them..

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta Your method 2 as stated is not all solutions in the general situation. (In particular, there can be less than $n$ terms in that sum in actuality.) But there is still an "undetermined coefficients" analogue to obtain the $t^k e^{ct}$ solutions when there is a defective eigenvalue. It's a less clean presentation, though, for sure.

Comment: Ok, i'm starting to think that is ok to bring $e^{-J(\omega)}t_0$ as you say at the right-side. Since left-side $P$ is already function of $\boldsymbol\omega$, being $P$ the matrix of eigenvectors, each of them related to a certain $\omega_i$, so it does not need additional $\boldsymbol\omega$ presence. While $\mathbf{c}$ can include $e^{-J(\omega)}t_0$, as by itself it's naturally dependent on $\boldsymbol\omega$ as $c_i$ coefficients were in fact chosen specifically for a certain $\omega_i$. Many thanks for the answer and the extended discussion, now i see things clearly.

Comment: And regarding $A$ if 'Method 2' is choosen i understand diagonalizability have to be assessed before proceeding

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta Correct, you need the eigenvalues, eigenvectors with their multiplicities, and if need be generalized eigenvectors, in order to actually carry out method 2 successfully.